# HTML5 Video working properly locally but not on hosted server

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, video

I am working with HTML5 video, its working fine locally but as I host the files on to the server its not getting any video file to be access at the browser. That's why video is not working with HTML5 Video tag.

I see the inspector then I revealed that the file isn't come to the browser end its showing the error that file is not present on to it.

from the header we can find that the contain type is text/html even I hosted the mp4 file at the server.

I am totally hanged finding the actual issue... Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the server doesn't have the correct MIME types configured for video. If you have access to the `.htaccess` file, you need to add the following lines:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/mp4 .m4v
AddType video/mp4 .m4p
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Comment: i dont know any setting and about this .htaccess file can you please give me the spteps to edit that file...am using win2008 server with IIS.

Comment: Ok, for IIS they are added differently. This should help you: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx